# Cannot install Ruby Sass on macOS

Tags: css, macos, sass, gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I had dart sass in my macOS Sierra(version 10.12.6). I uninstalled it to install ruby sass, the installation seems to be successful but when I check the version of sass I am getting an error message

```
$ gem install sass -v3.5.2
Successfully installed sass-3.5.2
Parsing documentation for sass-3.5.2
Done installing documentation for sass after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
Danys-MacBook-Pro:<FOLDERNAME> danyjose$ sass --version
-bash: /Users/danyjose/.nvm/versions/node/v6.0.0/bin/sass: No such file or directory`
```

I cannot figure out what I am missing here.